# How to use my own Git instead on Xcode's one?

Tags: xcode, git, versioning, homebrew

I installed Git 1.7.7.4 by homebrew, but Apple integrated Git into Xcode since version 4.
So in my computer, the default Git version is 1.7.5.4 which it's built-in Xcode 4.

I wonder if there's a way that let me use new version by default and would impact Xcode?

I tried add the path to $PATH:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar:$PATH
```

BTW, I'm using zsh.

Updated:
Thanks for @birryree's help, I'm using a wrong path, it should be /usr/local/bin, because of homebrew will use /usr/local/Cellar for storage, and use symlink to make sure all the packages are available on /usr/local/bin.

Comment: It's in `/usr/local/bin`, but I don't know if xcode hard codes using the one it installed into `/usr/bin`.

Comment: Well, homebrew installed Git under /usr/local/Cellar and set a symlink for it, so I guess should be Cellar.
Xcode does hard code using the /usr/bin. I hate it...
Thinks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my experience with my problems, have a check at [10449374](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449374/override-git-from-xcode-with-homebrew-version/) and [13177203](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13177203/unable-to-create-a-snapshot-in-xcode-4-5-1-after-update-the-gitconfig-option), this will help you:

1. change into the Xcode directory:

   `cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin`
2. rename the Xcode's git like this:

   `sudo mv ./git ./git-xcode-usr-bin`
3. link my own git which is installed through homebrew:

   `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/git ./git`

And you should do the same thing with `/usr/bin/git`:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/git /usr/bin/git-xcode-usr-bin
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/git /usr/bin/git
```

This will acctually link `/usr/local/Cellar/git/1.8.0/bin/git` (because I'm use git 1.8.0 at the present)

Comment: It's a horrible, hacky, solution and the OP doesn't even state why he wants to use a newer version of git.  Git is fairly broken in Xcode anyway (if you have any kind of merge issues) so I would recommend using SourceTree for all non-trival git operations: http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/

Comment: This is way way too hacky tacky to use. It's easier to prepend `/usr/local/bin` to your `PATH` variable; it is originally the last directory listed. Check out this answer ---> http://stackoverflow.com/a/10455668/393021

Answer (score 2):

There is a much easier way. In your shell's profile file (.bash_profile, .zshrc ect...), make an entry is its not already there:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

That will tell the shell that all packages installed by homebrew will override system defaults since homebrew creates aliases in that directory which points to your Cellar.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command:

brew link --overwrite git

This should make sure that the symlink happens and the right version of git is being used.

Comment: should be the accepted answer. In my case brew said it was already linked so I had to brew unlink git && brew link git

Answer (score 0):

Does `/usr/local/Cellar/git` exist?

I'd expect a path like `/usr/local/Cellar/`**bin**`/git`

Answer (score 0):

The chosen answer may break when you update xcode.

Instead, add something that looks like the following lines to your ~/.bash_profile

Modulo your git version installed by brew

```
### Added to use brew git
export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/git/1.8.1/bin/:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using fish shell with oh-my-fish and fix this problem after I set the plugin named brew in config.fish.

For zsh, if you use [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh), you can try to go to ~/.zshrc and add plugin named brew like "set plugins=(brew)"