# override git from Xcode with homebrew version

Tags: xcode, macos, git, path, homebrew

I've installed XCode and therefore git is there as well. Since i want to have a newer version of git I installed using homebrew.

But the homebrew version of git is never called since my PATH looks like this

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

which means the `/usr/bin/git` is allways called before `/usr/local/bin/git`.

Is there a way to change that without changing the PATH?

Comment: I created this script to have Xcode use your local installation of Git in /usr/local/bin. Check it out. https://gist.github.com/4659915

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Xcode is actually using the GIT that is stored in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin`.  The same version of GIT gets installed in `/usr/bin` when you installed the command line tools as part of Xcode installation.  So, you won't be able to change what Xcode is using (unless you are willing to muck with the contents of the Xcode package).  If, from a terminal application, you want to use the homebrew-installed GIT then you have two options:

1. Reference GIT with the full path as `/usr/local/bin/git ...`  For this case you can create an alias like `alias mgit=/usr/local/bin/git` and then use `mgit ...` from the terminal
2. Change the path as `PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` either in your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` if you use zsh file (or each time you start a terminal at the command line).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After all I changed the `PATH` in `/etc/paths` .

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364614/is-there-a-problem-with-having-usr-local-bin-before-usr-bin-on-the-path-in-os

Comment: On OS X Mountain Lion, I use ".bash_profile" instead of ".bashrc" - I've been doing this for years, though I don't know where I learned it, or why it works (and .bashrc doesn't.)

Comment: The name of the alias can still be just `git`, hasn't caused any problems for me and you get to keep the original name.

Answer (score 14):

Since Xcode hard coded its own version of git which is installed on `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git`, I managed to use this work around trick:

1. change into the Xcode directory:

   `cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin`
2. rename the Xcode's git like this:

   `sudo mv ./git ./git-xcode-usr-bin`
3. link my own git which is installed through homebrew:

   `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/git ./git`

And I did the same thing with `/usr/bin/git`

This will acctually link `/usr/local/Cellar/git/1.8.0/bin/git` (because I'm use git 1.8.0 at the present)

Certainly this may cause some other problems, such as when I upgrade the homebrew's verion git in the future, it would not work for me :( and I have to make a new link then.

I do it like this because I want to solve my own problem here [13177203](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13177203/unable-to-create-a-snapshot-in-xcode-4-5-1-after-update-the-gitconfig-option). And after search StackOverFlow for a long time, I finally got this solution.

Comment: While in general I avoid messing with packages like this, I did use this answer. Because of the change in `push.default` options in git 1.8, Xcode was giving me the following error and not allowing me to add assets to my project: `error: Malformed value for push.default: simple. error: Must be one of nothing, matching, tracking or current. fatal: bad config file line 7 of .gitconfig`. The other option would have been to change my gitconfig back to the 1.7 settings.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using [fish shell](http://fishshell.com) instead of bash, you can point to your preferred git binary by adding the following to `~/.config/fish/config.fish`.

```
function git
  /usr/local/bin/git $argv; 
end
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks for this tip. I didn't know you could do this in fish shell. It's very useful.