# Install Git before Boxen, or Boxen before Git?

Tags: macos, git, boxen

So, I've just ponied up for a Mac, and I'm looking to use Boxen to get a working environment setup. Thing is, the setup instructions are a little confusing. The intro on this page:

https://github.com/boxen/our-boxen#getting-started

uses git

```
sudo mkdir -p /opt/boxen
sudo chown ${USER}:admin /opt/boxen
git clone <location of my new git repository> /opt/boxen/repo
cd /opt/boxen/repo
script/boxen
```

but it then goes on to state:

```
This template project provides the following by default:

Homebrew
Git
Hub
```

I get the impression that you ideally want to have a clean system to avoid conflicts when using Boxen, so before I get git from homebrew/app store, I wanted to see how others have gone about setting up Boxen so I can save myself some headaches

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you need to install `git` first.  I've installed Boxen, although I haven't yet tried a clean bootstrap on a new machine.  Here's my understanding:

1) The X-Code Command-Line tools are a prerequisite for installing Boxen - [X-Code installs a version of `git` as `/usr/bin/git`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10455668/11296), so there is no need to explicitly install another `git` to bootstrap Boxen. On my machine - Mountain Lion/10.8.3:

```
$ /usr/bin/git --version
git version 1.7.12.4 (Apple Git-37)
```

2) Once you install Boxen, Boxen will then install the Homebrew release of git at `/opt/boxen/homebrew/bin/git`, which is likely a newer version of the X-Code Command-Line `git`:

```
$ /opt/boxen/homebrew/bin/git --version
git version 1.8.0
```

3) Finally, by default, Boxen will install `hub`, which will alias `git` to `hub` ([`hub` is a GitHub-enhancing wrapper around `git`](https://github.com/defunkt/hub#readme)):

```
$ type -a git
git is aliased to `hub'
git is /opt/boxen/homebrew/bin/git
git is /usr/bin/git

$ git --version
git version 1.8.0
hub version 1.10.5
```

Answer (score 1):

I let Xcode command line tools do it for me, before I setup a fresh Boxen:

```
$ xcode-select --install
```

After you setup your Boxen, you'll be up to the appropriate Git version.