# Giving Homebrew packages precedence over Darwin in PATH

Tags: xcode, git, path, homebrew

I recently updated my brew packages and noticed that there was an update to Git. I wanted to check out what it was some time later and punched in `which git`. To my surprise, the **version of Git it returned was Darwin**, not my fancy schmancy Homebrew installed Git 2.something.

I'm confused.

I have my PATH set at the bottom of .zshrc as:

`export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH"`

and in etc/paths I moved `usr/local/bin` and `usr/local/sbin` above `usr/bin` in the list.

**and yet `which git` returns `usr/bin/git`**

I know that xcode uses the same version that's in usr/bin, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449374/override-git-from-xcode-with-homebrew-version), but I could've sworn I managed to get this overridden before.

Any help you can give is appreciated.

## EDIT

`echo $PATH` returns:

`/Users/bwstud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/Users/bwstud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/bin:/Users/bwstud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/user/local/bin /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/bwstud/.rvm/bin`

Comment: What's `echo $PATH` say? I don't think there's anything magical about git.

Comment: Does `/usr/local/bin/git` exist and is it executable?  Have you run `rehash` or restarted your shell after the package upgrade?