# Upgrade Git 1.9.3 on Mac OS X or not?

Tags: xcode, git, heroku, osx-yosemite

Xcode installed Git 1.9.3 on Mac OS X 10.10.1.

When I run Heroku, the following message shows up:

> Your version of git is 1.9.3. Which has serious security
>   vulnerabilities. More information here:
>   https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/12/23/update_your_git_clients_on_windows_and_os_x

Should I download from Git from official website and upgrade to 2.x? Will it affect Xcode's operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am running git 2.1.2 and everything seems fine, including Xcode – I use git extensively there. I installed using [homebrew](http://brew.sh), and I highly recommend using that method if you plan to upgrade.

Comment: Good to hear that. I have homebrew installed too. But, will the next Xcode update downgrade the Git, or make the Xcode installation failed?

Comment: No, neither. I've upgraded Xcode as well. Remember that the brew version gets installed in a different place than system git, which will not be touched, and your PATH is simply updated.

Comment: Thanks. In case someone wants to know the command of updating / installing Git, here it is: `brew install git` ( remember to install homebrew first )

Comment: I updated git to 2.2.2 via homebrew, but the Mac still using old Git (1.9.3). Seems the path doesn't get updated.

Comment: Make sure your `$PATH` has `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin`. Homebrew's git is installed in the former location, and OS X's git is in the latter. Also, note that [Xcode will not use the new version of git by default](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10455668/1292061).